# Performing localized raster edits using ArcGIS Spatial Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, editing, masking

I have a raster image of water depth, float point values 1-15, in a very small area some erroneous values are in the raster with values of 100 - 375.  I'm looking for a repeatable work flow in ArcMap 10.5, Spatial Analyst level.  I've used one work flow to set the values to nodata, one work flow to set to a fixed float point value, but what I'd really like is to create polygon or raster mask, and then have the grids of the original raster, within the mask area, to be replaced with nearest neighbor values from the original raster outside the mask area.

Answer (score 2):

The tool you are looking for is [nibble](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/nibble.htm).  Nibble does exactly what you are asking for. Your work flow would be something along the lines of using your polygons to create a mask raster as the second input.  Other related tools to consider (but probably not what you want for this use-case) are [shrink](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/shrink.htm) and [expand](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/expand.htm).

Comment: I tried Nibble and did not get the desired results, that why I came here.  I not performing the workflow correctly in someway

Comment: Nibble is the correct tool.  Re-read the documentation carefully and I think you'll find the solution.

Comment: nibble is for integers documentation says http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Nibble/009z00000038000000/

Comment: You can make an integer raster based on your original multiplied by 1000 (or whatever decimal precision you want), perform the nibble operation then divide by 1000 - it's a common solution where you are forced to work with integers.

Comment: I was looking for a more concise workflow  - maybe with Con or Raster Calculator, that could somehow avoid the conversion.  The raster calculator examples I found online did not work for me,  Con(IsNull(Raster), FocalStatistics(Raster, NbrCircle(10, "CELL"), "MEAN"), Raster)

Comment: thanks for continuing the conversation btw

Comment: NP - if you build it into Model Builder then the conversion is not an issue and you get a very repeatable workflow that you can use to iterate over a whole set of rasters if required.

Comment: Thank you.. I will use that approach you are suggesting.